# Best sparse matrix representation for column and row swaping

Tags: c++, data-structures, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am looking for sparse matrix representation that allow for efficient row and column swaping. The classic representation (by compressed row,compressed column or triplets) seems to only allow to perform one or the other but never booth.
Any one know a good data structure for this ?

--Edit--
To clarify , i want to be able to swap rows, like swap row 5 and row 7, and also swap column like swap column 6 and column 8.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the classic representation' ?  I know about half-a-dozen ways of storing sparse matrices, each of them suitable for some operations, each unsuitable for some operations.

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient row and column swapping' ?  Do you want to, for example, swap row 1 with column 3; or do you want to transpose the entire matrix ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I understood it as being able to swap row 1 with 5 efficiently and swap column 4 with 9 efficiently as well, but not mixing row and columns... Guess it means the question is really difficult to get :x

Comment: i added some clarification to the question, i want to swap between rows, and between column , not a mix of booth

Comment: Someone can probably find a counterexample, but those most representations good for column swapping are generally not good for row swapping and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just want to just add another level of indirection to handle swapping whichever is not efficient.  For example, if you have a sparse representation that can efficiently swap rows but not columns, then have an array that maps from the true columns to the effective columns.  When you access an element, use the array to find the proper underlying element.

```
class SparseMatrix {
  public:
    Element& operator()(Index row,Index col)
    {
      return matrix(row,col_map[col]);
    }

    void swapRows(Index row1,Index row2)
    {
      matrix.swapRows(row1,row2);
    }

    void swapCols(Index col1,Index col2)
    {
      swap(col_map[col1],col_map[col2]);
    }

  private:
    FastRowSwapSparseMatrix matrix;
    vector<Index> col_map;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is

Eigen: Very fast and efficient for Linear algebra operations
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/

or

Mapped Matrix in boost --> more flexible, but slower for linear algebra operations 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm

For your case, both libraries allow you to manipulate rows and columns efficiently